# How to change the size of an image inserted with "::before" or "::after" peudo-element in CSS

Tags: html, css

How to change the size of an `image` inserted with the `::before` pseudo-element in CSS?

here is my code

```
.smile::before {
    content: url(../../../../Pictures/Smilie.jpg);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: your question is not clear, what you need exactly

Comment: Change the size of the inserted image with CSS "::before" pseudo-element.

Comment: On my code the "height and the width" property is not working but apparently it cannot be sized this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi why dont you add your image as a background image and add the following

```
.smile::before{
  content: ' ';
  background-image: url(../../../../Pictures/Smilie.jpg);
  background-size:contain;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
 }
```

Comment: i couldnt get it to work until i inserted "background-size: contain" - thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

A good solution to your question is that you have to use your image as a background.

```
.smile::before{
   content: ' ';
   background: url(../../../../Pictures/Smilie.jpg);
   background-size:contain;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hi everyone I've tried this code but it is not working as it is!

Comment: I finally figured out that it the "content" itself has to be "display:inline-block" because only "block" element can have their proper size!

Comment: Here is the code what works

Comment: .smile::before{
   content: ' ';
   display:inline-block;
   background: url(../../../../Pictures/Smilie.jpg);
   background-size:contain;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}

Comment: I would post this as the accepted solution